# Javascript eval in function

Tags: javascript, function, variables

I want to make a function that has to generate a random number between 2 numbers and you can save it in a variable. I'm using this code:

```
function rand(ran1, ran2, randVar) {
    var randomNumb = Math.floor(Math.random()*(ran2 - ran1)) + ran1;
    eval("var " +randVar+ " = "+randomNumb+";"); 
}
rand(12, 49, rand1)
alert("Your number is: "+rand1)
```

The error I get is: `Can't find variable: rand1`

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Where is "rand1" declared?

Comment: It can't find `rand1` because you never made `rand1`

Comment: Your variable is "ran1" not "rand1"

Comment: I think you'd want `rand(12, 49, "rand1")`, but you shouldn't use this method just to declare a variable

Comment: If you really want to do it this way, use an object, then you don't have to eval and you can manipulate its values from within your function.

Comment: I recommend to read some tutorials about functions: http://quirksmode.org/js/function.html, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions

Comment: Funny thing is that this code is probably overriding the `undefined` variable! (Silently fails in ES6 I think, or maybe even ES5)

Comment: @CamiloMartin: Not really. Since `rand1` is not defined, it throws a a reference error. The code does not run.

Comment: @FelixKling Ah, you're right!

Answer (score 7):

Using `eval` for this is entirely unnecessary. I'd recommend something like this instead:

```
function rand(ran1, ran2) {
    var randomNumb = Math.floor(Math.random()*(ran2 - ran1)) + ran1;
    return randomNumb;
}

var rand1 = rand(12, 49);
alert("Your number is: " + rand1);
```

Notice that in calling the function, the only real difference is in where you place the identifier, `rand1`.

**Further Reading**

- [Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions)
- [`return`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return)

Comment: You don't even need to save the random number to a variable first. You could just use `return Math.floor(...)`

Comment: @ColeJohnson Correct, but I wanted to highlight exactly what I changed here.